# Google project hosting svn commit problem

Tags: svn, project-hosting

When I try to commit my code with svn commit, it returns an error :

> svn: Commit failed (details follow): 
>       svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) 
>       in response to MKACTIVITY request for
>   '/svn/!svn/act/acf5cd6f-e8d7-476e-a572-a61a5d293586'

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I used to be like you, and this is how I fix
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051221/what-happend-to-my-google-code-svn/20654382#20654382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching to `https` looks like this is a bug in Google Code system, see [`Google Code Bug #1916`](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=1916)