# What happend to my google code svn?

Tags: svn, google-code

Why it would not commit (I had done more than 200 commits on my google code account into that single project and now it somehow stops me from committing =(
tortois SVN:

```
Commit
Commit failed (details follow):
Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to 
MKACTIVITY request for '/svn/!svn/act/81a42074-ce30-7442-90d9-99893693ce62'
```

SharpSVN

```
SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: Commit failed (details follow): ---> SharpSvn.SvnRepositoryIOException: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/svn/!svn/act/651b9f6b-736c-534d-b0e6-29c7071ef741'
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at Ankh.Services.PendingChanges.PendingChangeHandler.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Commit_CommitToRepository>b__14(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs e)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

I tried on different files on diffrent brunces but same error all way long=( What shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this problem. Solved by deleting my auth cache in VS.NET:  Tools -> Options... -> Source Control -> Subversion Environnment -> Authentication Cache Edit -> Remove your server/realm

Answer (score 4):

Just try this:

```
svn switch --relocate http://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ \
                      https://foo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ \
           --username foo@bar.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that your casing is correct - svn is case sensitive. If you try to commit with a differently cased url from your repository has, it will try to commit a new repo (this is standard in the unix world where you can have 2 files called README and readme in the same directory). However, the back-end system will not let you create a new repo just from a commit and returns that error.

That generally returns you a 403 error, so I'm not sure if it's the same error for Googlecode.

I do know that googlecode will give you the 405 error if you try to commit using http when you should be using https.

Comment: What does scary "MKACTIVITY" meant?

Comment: Means "Make Activity". It records the activity in log file.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue using eclipse + subclipse.

Solved it by disconnecting from the svn and then connect again. (team-> disconnect)

Answer (score 0):

in windows 
select folder checkout -> click right mouse -> choose tortois SVN -> choose relocate

change url `http://xxxxx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`
to `https://xxxxx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`

[See this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAX5w.png)